# MySQL - Select and Update existing wrong 0 Values (0000-00-00 00:00:00) to Correct DateTime Values

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

There is an existing "DateTime" Column with incorrect DateTime Values.

Values are "0000-00-00 00:00:00".

So because of this I alter my table in this way:

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table` MODIFY `my_datetime` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL;
```

Now I want to update the wrong values to NULL.

But this query does not work:

```
UPDATE `my_table`
SET `my_datetime` = NULL
WHERE `my_datetime` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

I got this error message:

> Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column
>   'my_datetime' at row 1

But If I try to select the values I got a result.

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table`
WHERE `my_datetime` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

SO how can I update ALL my wrong Values to NULL?

Comment: `Values are "0000-00-00 00:00:00".` ... not easily, since the [smallest supported year is 1000](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html).

Comment: yes the problem is that this format is now in my table... so I have to correct it, but I dont know how.

Comment: Hmmm...what does `SELECT MIN(my_datetime) FROM my_table` show you?

Comment: I got "0000-00-00 00:00:00".

Answer (score 2):

it is possible with ALLOW_INVALID_DATES,
because Mysql 5.7 is very strict.

```
SET sql_mode = 'ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';
UPDATE my_table
SET my_datetime = NULL 
WHERE my_datetime = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```